# How to optimize my Android flash game?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I have a game that I converted to my Android phone. I tried both renders, and found out that CPU mode is a better option than GPU for my type of game. In GPU mode, the game has a lot of lag and the graphics are not sharp as it is in CPU mode. The purpose of the game is to kill enemies coming from the top of the screen before they hit the bottom. When the game starts, it's not laggy at all, but then it starts to lag when there are a few enemies on the screen and they start coming down faster. This is the code of spawning the enemies:

```
function makeEnemies():void
{
    var chance:Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 150);
    if (chance <= level && enemies.length < 4)
    {
        tempEnemy = new Enemy();
        tempEnemy.x = Math.round(Math.random() * 480);
        tempEnemy.cacheAsBitmap = true;
        addChild(tempEnemy);
        tempEnemy.scaleX = 1.5;
        tempEnemy.scaleY = 1.5;
        enemies.push(tempEnemy);

        tempEnemy.speed = enemyBaseSpeed + ((level - 1) * speedLevelInc);
        if (tempEnemy.speed > MAX_SPEED)
        {
            tempEnemy.speed = MAX_SPEED;

        }


    }

}


function moveEnemies():void
{
    var tempEnemy:MovieClip;


    for (var i:int =enemies.length-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        tempEnemy = enemies[i];
        if (tempEnemy.dead)
        {
            score++;
            score++;
            roachLevel.score_txt.text = String(score);
            enemies.splice(i,1);

        }
        else
        {

            tempEnemy.rotation += (Math.round(Math.random()*.4));
            tempEnemy.x -=  (Math.sin((Math.PI/180)*tempEnemy.rotation))*tempEnemy.speed;
            tempEnemy.y +=  (Math.cos((Math.PI/180)*tempEnemy.rotation))*tempEnemy.speed;
            if (tempEnemy.x < 10)
            {
                tempEnemy.x = 11;
            }
            if (tempEnemy.x > stage.stageWidth - offset)
            {
                tempEnemy.x = stage.stageWidth - offset;
            }
            if (tempEnemy.y > stage.stageHeight)
            {
                removeEnemy(i);

                lives--;
                roachLevel.lives_txt.text = String(lives);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code is always looped to spawn multiple enemies. All my images have been converted to bitmaps. Is there any other way for me to make my game with no lag? The faster they get, the more lag they have and the user can't kill them anymore. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

There are certain optimizations you can make (whether or not it's enough I can't tell):

1. you don't need cacheAsBitmap if you've converted everything to bitmaps, so comment this out
2. don't set scale!  this will definitely slow things down.  Since scale always seems to be 1.5, just resize your graphics
3. don't set tempEnemy.rotation on each iteration, if possible.  Can you make tempEnemy a MovieClip that "pre-rotates" each frame in the timeline?  This will be way more efficient for Flash.  The rotation can be set as a Number property in the MovieClip class if you still need it for calculating tempEnemy.x and y.
4. (There are several minor things you can optimize, like setting var K = (Math.PI/180)*tempEnemy.rotation) in the enemies loop-- but this won't gain you a lot)